# Will the introduction of sharding have an effect on the functionality of currently deployed smart contracts or the EVM?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm, plasma, sharding

Is there any risk the the hard fork required for sharding or Plasma to take effect on the Ethereum network will cause compatibility issues for contracts already deployed?

Will the protocol in place whenever sharding is enacted be backwards compatible with current contracts (such as Tokens, etc).

Thanks for any help. I'm struggling to understand how it will effect this aspect of Ethereum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phase 1 sharding](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-roadmap) won't have any execution or EVM, so it won't integrate with the main net. Phase 2 will have an EVM, and will introduce backwards incompatible changes at a smart contract level, like storage rent, however the intention is to try to make these changes as DX and UX friendly as possible. (See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#you-mentioned-transparent-sharding-im-12-years-old-and-what-is-this; also see the links at the storage rent point here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-roadmap#phase-2-evm-state-transition-function.)

Basic sharding design: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#what-might-a-basic-design-of-a-sharded-blockchain-look-like.

As an [L2 solution](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#how-does-plasma-state-channels-and-other-layer-2-technologies-fit-into-the-trilemma), Plasma will have to be compatible with whatever the current blockchain spec is.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation on exactly how this can be made more DX and UX friendly? Also, will the current EVM continue to be run on Ethereum nodes or will it be considered something else (like Ethereum Classic 2.0) once a sharding hard fork happens?

Comment: See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#you-mentioned-transparent-sharding-im-12-years-old-and-what-is-this.

Also see the links at the storage rent point: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-roadmap#phase-2-evm-state-transition-function

Nodes: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#what-might-a-basic-design-of-a-sharded-blockchain-look-like.

Comment: Updated links for first and third: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQs#you-mentioned-transparent-sharding-im-12-years-old-and-what-is-this and https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQs#what-might-a-basic-design-of-a-sharded-blockchain-look-like. There will need to be a hard fork, so node operators will need to upgrade their client to the latest version that supports the hard fork. Of course there is always a chance with a hard fork that it won't be clean, and that some operators continue using an old version, like Ethereum Classic.